# Speed of Azure File Service

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu-14.04, azure-storage

Reading the documentation regarding Azure File Service I expected an easy and fast way to mount more space to my virtual Azure machine. However, after mounting a file service on my ubuntu machine (done exactly as explained on this page) I get super slow read/write speeds to this mount.

To give an example, downloading a 1000mb.bin file to my local disk:

```
sander@sanderpihost:~$ wget http://www.colocenter.nl/speedtest/1000mb.bin
--2015-06-28 08:34:38--  http://www.colocenter.nl/speedtest/1000mb.bin
Resolving www.colocenter.nl (www.colocenter.nl)... 5.39.184.5
Connecting to www.colocenter.nl (www.colocenter.nl)|5.39.184.5|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1048576000 (1000M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘1000mb.bin’

12% [==========>                                                                                ] 134,018,596 37.3MB/s  eta 25s
```

And to my mounted folder:

```
sander@sanderpihost:~/myazuredisk/Incomplete$ wget http://www.colocenter.nl/speedtest/1000mb.bin
--2015-06-28 08:31:39--  http://www.colocenter.nl/speedtest/1000mb.bin
Resolving www.colocenter.nl (www.colocenter.nl)... 5.39.184.5
Connecting to www.colocenter.nl (www.colocenter.nl)|5.39.184.5|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1048576000 (1000M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘1000mb.bin.1’

 0% [                                                                                           ] 3,768,320    466KB/s  eta 34m 8s
```

Is this expected? Is there any reason why this is soo slow? I would expect to hit much higher speeds than this meagre ±500KB/s I seem to get right now.

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, as it's 100% infrastructure / server / network related, not programming-related.

Comment: Can you try mount the file share from a Windows VM (e.g. Windows Server 2012) and run the same test, so that we can tell if this is something network related or client OS related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network speed depends on instance size. A0 (extra small) instance with shared core (0.25) and 768MB of RAM has only 5Mbit/s bandwidth. Try to change instance size and test. In theory, Azure Files performance should be around 60MB/s (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/) on standard storage.

Comment: The network bandwidth for virtual machines is no longer published (aside from the high-end network-optimized VMs), and the 5Mb/s bandwidth number is not valid. That information is from several years ago.

Comment: @DavidMakogon weirdly enough, opting for a larger VM did boost my performance to the speeds that I was expecting. So, for some reason, the smallest server will not let, for me at least, get the expected 60MB/s speeds.

Comment: I wasn't arguing that. I'm saying the specs for a given VM's bandwidth are unpublished, and that's what should be removed from @michal's Answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon A0 is limited to 5Mb/s :) Just test it and You will see ;)